# Turn picture to movie

Tags: php, javascript, flash

How to use `javascript`,`PHP` or other to turn photos which user upload to server into a movie?

For example I want to turn photos `1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg` which in `C:\htdocs\img\pic` into `1.avi` or other `video` formats.

Thanks.

Comment: You want to convert pictures to audio format? (I suppose you mean video) Does it have to be downloadable of would a simple imageslider work as well?

Comment: i don't think javascript can do anything like this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest sollution for that is to use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)

```
convert *jpg mymovie.mpg
```